# Terminate a called function after some time

Tags: javascript

provided the following code:

```
function update() {
var ret = someFun();
}
function someFun() {
while(true) { var i = 0 }
}
```

Is it possible that update stops waiting for a return of the function call after a given time without changing someFun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible that update stops waiting for a return of the function call after a given time without changing someFun?

**No.**

Nothing can intervene with the current execution context. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

> #### "Run-to-completion"
>
> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it can be stopped at any point to run some other code in another thread.

Comment: Well, not i wanted to hear, but exactly what i was looking for.